# Snow Leopard vs. Lion performance: what are the differences?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, performance

Is Snow Leopard or Lion faster?

And how significant is the speed difference?

Comment: lion runs a 64-bit kernel, but the performance is most likely dependent of the app.

Answer (score 4):

There's very little difference.

Check out this cnet review it shows the performance of applications like Photoshop, Call of Duty 4 etc. on a 27" 2011 iMac running Snow Leopard & Lion:
http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-20081987-1/snow-leopard-vs-lion-performance-head-to-head/, which concludes:

> For the most part, we found only minor speed variations between the
>   two operating systems.

Comment: With some summarizing, you could turn not-an-answer to a good answer :-) see: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/485/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-link-acceptable

Comment: Read the guidelines found on the link you provided & edited my answer, hope it is acceptable now. Thx for the guidance

Comment: That's still not an answer! From the article: "For the most part, we found only minor speed variations between the two operating systems. Lion seemed a touch slower in our Photoshop CS5 batch processing test, but it also has a similarly small edge in iTunes encoding. We can't explain the variations with certainty, but it seems that iTunes does indeed benefit from the shift to 64-bit support. For Photoshop CS5, which does not yet support Lion's versioning capability, the performance dip could come from background code tied to versioning, or perhaps it's simply an optimization issue."

Comment: How about now?
Sry about this I'm still new around here XD